# Dropdownlist with ok button will trigger search textbox and search button to visible in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, drop-down-menu

Here I have a DropDownList and Button ok that when clicked, it will enable visibility of other search textbox and search button. Also, this depend on what I select DropDownList item. Say, in my DropDownList, I have ProductName and ProductCode.I now select ProductName Next to this ddlist is button ok. When I click button ok, control such as label, textboxName and buttonSearchName will appear below of it.
How can I accomplish this?

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>ProductName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ProductCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Category</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>SellingPrice</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Quantity</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>BrandName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ReOrderQty</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ReOrderLevel</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Ordered</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Allocated</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>FreeQty</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" onclick="btnOK_Click" Text="OK" />
            <br />
            ProductName<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchProductname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchProductName" runat="server" Text="search" 
                onclick="btnSearchProductName_Click" />
            <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, one way to do it is (as answered before me) to add an update panel and set visibility to False, but then you would also require a ScriptManager and if you have other controls in the same page (such as a FileUpload control) that will not work properly with the presence of a ScriptManager.

You could alternatively use the same TextBox to search for all of the fields, by implementing a method that detects the value selected in your DropDownList and based on that value, the search algorithm changes accordingly.

So I just renamed your `txtSearchProduct` to just `txtSearch` and I added a universal method to search all criteria named `btnSearch_Click`

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>ProductName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ProductCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Category</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>SellingPrice</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Quantity</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>BrandName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ReOrderQty</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>ReOrderLevel</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Ordered</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Allocated</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>FreeQty</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            Search: <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server">
                    </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="search" 
                onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
            <br />
```

and here is an example of what would the `btnSearch_Click` look like

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = this.txtSearch.Text;

    switch (this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString) {
        case "ProductName":
            string sql = "select * from products where ProductName like '%" + searchText + "%'";
        // the rest of your code goes here
            break;

        case "ProductCode":
            string sql = "select * from products where ProductCode like '%" + searchText + "%'";
        // populate some other control with your productcode search here
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yup,it should be like this.As long as it is working properly, suffice to do this.Thanks, friend.How to vote you as an answer to this?U deserved it.

Comment: You will find a a blank check mark under the ^0 next to my answer, and if you hover your mouse next to it it will say (Accept This Answer)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, but since your just starting the easiest thing to do would be to put your controls in a panel and change the visibility in your "btnOK_Click" event.

**Example:**

```
<asp:Panel id="searchPanel" runat="server" visible="false">
   your controls here....
</asp:Panel>
```

To make this visible, in your event use the following syntax.

```
searchPanel.Visible = True;
```

Comment: Nice!But how to use ddllist when I select other item such as ProductCode? Should panelProductName dissapear? Or in same panel(my panel is panel1) but only trigger to display only controls associated to productCode?

Comment: So each option in your drop down list will have a different set of controls, right?  Easiest way using traditional ASP.NET postbacks would be to create 1 panel per/option.  Then you can specify the panel to show/hide, based on the drop down list selected item.  You might also want to create a helper function that you can call that will hide all panels, and show only the panel you want to see.  You would call it like "ShowPanel(productCodePanel)", and it would hide all panels and show only the "productCodePanel".